# Should I pass private state with params to functions or should functions use the private state?

Tags: angular, architecture

I have an Angular app with the following scenario, although I believe this scenario is suitable for other frameworks/scenario's too:

```
public export class FooComponent {
    private userId: number;

    constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.userId = authService.GetUser().id;

        this.getDataByUserId(this.userId);    
    }

    private getDataByUserId(userId: number) { 
        // Load data using the param
    }

    public anotherFunction(fooId: number) {
       // Gets called by an event occurring or something
       // Perform an API Call

       // Now reload the data by using the private state variable.
       this.getDataByUserId(this.userId);
    }
}
```

Should `getDataByUserId(userId: number)` use a parameter to receive the userId, or should it be parameter-less and just access the `private userId` of the component?

In my mind, the pro's and con's of passing the variable as a param are the following:

**Pro's**
- Easier unit testing; if the component is a bit bigger you might not need to set up the component in a specific way to work, you only need to pass a number
- If many functions of your component access that one variable and change it, you might end up in scenario's where the variable is in an invalid state.

**Con's**
- If you don't set up the component in a specific way anymore since you can just pass the value as a param, the "state" of the your component during the test might not reflect the expected state during a production scenario. Since your test does not reflect real working conditions they might be considered brittle.
- If you pass the wrong value, things will/can go wrong.

What is considered the better option here? Where does one draw the line?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the real purpose of the `getUserDataById` function.

Is it always called with the `userId` stored in the component's state (so it's some kind of `currentUserId`)? Then it would be better to make a `getCurrentUserData` method without parameters that will always take the userID from the state and test it as such.

If you reuse it in different parts of your component or application with different user ID sources then it seems logical to make it a separate function and test it without dependencies in components' states. Then when you test `anotherFunction` you should mock `getUserDataById`when needed.